# Node JS + Express : Masked URL

Tags: node.js, express

I am using AWS to host my node js app, with a public IP 1.2.3.4 and I have a domain name "abc.com" which is registered using a different provider, I am using URL masking to hide the IP in the browser. So, abc.com will redirect me to http://1.2.3.4.

The issue I am facing is, I have some static files which are under the app folder in node js. So when I am doing http://1.2.3.4/app it shows me the index.html which works fine, but when I type abc.com/app it doesn't work. Where do I need to handle that routing? I also use express

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after some digging around, I figured out that path-forwarding was not turned on. Those changes need to be done with the domain service provider. Turning on the path-forwarding fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

So, make virtual private server, setup redirect from you'r domain to ip address this vps and check this for 24 hours. This work for me easy.